# Form generator for WPF (Entity Framework)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there any free form generator that can create a WPF form from the files of a data collection (Entity frame work). I am using entity frame work and SQL CE. What is the best way to create an input form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall a presentation showing this is a built-in ability in Visual Studio 2010,  .NET 4.0.

I can't remember how it was done, but try dragging entity from model browser above a window or control in the designer.

Comment: Thanks. It puts a datagrid on the wpf form and bind it to entity. and yes it can create a form instead of grid. Thanks